# Issues with PHP array and API

Tags: php, arrays

im working on a project on SEMRUSH api and results are coming trhough in $field1;field2   so seperated by ;

current result i get has so 5 reslts next to each other based on its columns, however i need second array only

```
     if (isset($_POST['search_term'])) {

       $kwtext1 = str_replace(" ", '+', ($_POST['search_term']));
       $kwtext = str_replace("\r", '', trim($kwtext1));
       $kwdata = array();
        $kwlines = explode("\n", $kwtext);

       $db = "us";
       $limit = "10";
       }


    foreach ($kwlines as $kw) {

    usleep(100);

    $u = 'http://' . $db . '.api.semrush.com/?action=report&type=phrase_this&phrase=' . $kw . '&key=' . $key . '&display_limit=' . $limit . '&display_offset=0&export=api&export_columns=Ph,Nq,Cp,Co,Nr';

      $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $u);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

      $answer        = curl_exec      ( $ch );

    $kwdata = explode ( "\n", trim ( $answer ) );
     $kwfields = explode ( ";", array_shift ( $kwdata ) );

      if ( count ( $kwdata ) > 0 )
      {
    ?>
    <table class="output">
    <tr><th>Domain 1</th>
   <?php $csv_output .= ' ' . ", " . 'Domain' . ", ";?>

    <?
        foreach ( $kwfields as $field )
        {
  ?>
      <th><?= $field; ?></th>
    <?php $csv_output .= $field . ", ";?>
    <?
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
    <?
        foreach ( $kwdata as $dataline )
        {
          $values = explode ( ";", $dataline, count ( $kwfields ) );
     ?>
    <tr><td><? echo $kw ?></td>
    <?php $csv_output .= $kw . ", ";?>
   <?
             foreach ( $values as $value )
          {
    ?>
      <td><?= $value; ?></td>
   <?php $csv_output .= $value . ", ";?>
    <?
            }
  ?>
    </tr>
          <?
        }
         ?>
        </table>
     <?
      }
         else
        {
       ?>
           No data found for your request
       <?
              }
     }


      ?>
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the second result, and you KNOW you are going to have 5 results, then I suppose changing line:

```
$kwfields = explode(";", array_shift($kwdata));
```

to:

```
$kwfields = explode(";", $kwdata[1]);
```

will work.

But if you don't have at least 2 rows of data this will fail. Are you guaranteed to get 2 or more? if not then you will need to have a check around this.

Comment: it doesnt return anything eitherways

Comment: Leys say you wanna get second result here foreach ( $values as $value )
          {
}

Comment: `foreach($values as $i => $value) { if ($i == 1) { /* stuff */ } }`